# Let $S$ be a discrete set of points on a line. Does there always exist a subset of $\mathbb{Z}^2$ whose projection on the line is $S$?

Tags: integer-lattices, quasiperiodic-function

I am exploring projections of the integer lattice on a line $r$ passing through the origin.

I understand that the projection of a periodic 2D lattice on a line can be non periodic (a 1D quasicrystal, if I understand correctly).
I am trying to tackle the following (kind of inverse) problem: given a discrete set $S$ on the line $r$, when is it possible to find a subset of $\mathbb{Z}^2$ such that its orthogonal projection on the line is exactly $S$?

I can see the solution when $S$ is "periodic", i.e. when the points of $S$ are evenly spaced on the line by a fixed distance $\omega$, but what about more general cases? I don't know even where to begin...

Comment: Do you mean a discrete set, or a finite one? It might be possible to find a counterexample for some infinite-but-countable discrete set, but not for a finite set.

Comment: I really am interested in infinite "doubly quasi periodic" sets, i.e. a union of two periodic sets on the line with incommensurable periods. I guess the general answer is that there exist sets on the line that aren't projections, but I'm more interested in the case when such sets are indeed projections.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is, I believe, "no". Here's my reasoning.
$$
\newcommand{zz} {{\mathbb Z}}
$$
First, instead of considering the points of $S$ to be along some line through the origin (tilted at some angle $\theta$ clockwise from the $x$-axis), and projecting the lattice onto that line, let's consider our line to be the $x$-axis, and the lattice to be rotated counterclockwise by angle $\theta$. Thus a typical point of the lattice has coordinates
$$
k (\cos \theta, \sin \theta) + n (-\sin \theta, \cos \theta)
$$
I'll refer to this point as $[k, n]$ to save writing all those sines and cosines. Now the "projection" onto the line amounts to $[k, n] \mapsto k \cos \theta - n\sin \theta$, but that will be almost entirely irrelevant.

This picture shows the initial setup: integer lattice in black, sloped line in purple, a typical point $[2, 1]$ picked out, and its projection onto the line (red arrow, orange point).

[image]

After rotation by the angle $\theta$ (described as $t$ in the picture), the purple line becomes the $x$-axis, but the lattice point retains its name $[2, 1]$, even though the lattice is rotated by angle $\theta$.

Second, let's look at a kind of set mentioned in your comment, namely
$$
S = \{n \alpha \mid n \in \zz \} \cup \{n \beta \mid n \in \zz \}
$$
which I'll rewrite as
$$
S = \alpha \zz \cup \beta  \zz,
$$
but for the special case $\alpha = \dfrac12$. I'll say what $\beta$ is shortly, but for now, it's just some number.

We're asking the question "Is there some sub-lattice of $\zz^2$ that projects to $S$?" Let's for the moment **suppose** that there *is*; then some point $[u, v]$ must project to $\alpha = 1/2$, and some point $[s, t]$ must project to $\beta$. (It's possible that multiple points will project to each, but I only need to name one.)

So let's look at each possible nonzero lattice point $[u, v]$ and ask "Is there some value of $\theta$ for which $[u, v]$ projects to $1/2$?" The point $[u, v]$ is at distance $r = \sqrt{u^2 + v^2}$ from the origin, so as $\theta$ ranges through all possible angles, $[u, v]$ sweeps out a circle of radius $r$ around the origin. Because $[u, v]$ is nonzero, $r$ is at least one. So this circle intersects the line $x = 1/2$ in two points. So there are two angles at which $[u, v]$ will project to the number $\alpha = 1/2$. (Explicitly, at $\theta_{uv} = \pm (\arccos(\frac{1/2}{r})-arccos(u/r))$, but we won't need that.)

To make this last remark explicit, let's look at the point shown in the first diagram above, $(2, 1)$. Its distance from the origin is $r = \sqrt{5} \approx 1.618$; its angle from the $x$-axis is $\arccos(2/\sqrt{5})\approx 26^{\circ}$. Rotating it by an angle of about $t = 50.5$ degrees sends it to
$$
(2 \cos t - 1 \sin t, 2 \sin t + 1 \cos t) \approx
(2 \times 0.636 - 0.772, 2 \times .772 + 0.636) \approx (0.5, 2.18).
$$

And in fact, rotating by angle $t$ or $-t$ are the only ways to make $[2, 1]$ project to the value $1/2$ on the $x$-axis.

Summary so far: if we want to find a rotated sublattice projecting to $S$, with $[u, v]$ projecting to $\frac{1}{2}$, then there are exactly two angles $\pm \theta_{uv}$ by which the lattice can be rotated to achieve this.

Since we're assuming there's a sublattice and projection solution, we know that if $[u, v]$ projects to $1/2$, then the angle must be $\pm \theta_{uv}$.

Now let's look at where *other* points of this rotated integer lattice might project. They'll project to some countably-infinite set of points, which I'm going to call $H_{uv}$. In particular, the projection of the special point $[s, t]$ --- the one that projects to $\beta$ --- must be in $H_{uv}$, or in other words, we must have $\beta \in H_{uv}$. This picture

[image]

shows how part of the rest of the (rotated) integer lattice from the earlier diagrams might project onto the line --- the red dots are the projections. If we squint a little and suppose that the point $[1, 2]$ (corresponding to the leftmost tall arrow) is actually projecting to the $x$-coordinate $0.5$ (it's not really!), then this set of red dots (and the others that I didn't draw) would be $H_{[1,2]}$.

Summary so far: if there's a sublattice projecting to $S$, and $[u, v]$ is a point of the sublattice that projects to $1/2$, then $\beta$ must be in $H_{uv}$.

Now let us ignore that "suppose" above, and ask "*Could* there be a rotated sublattice that projects to $S$?" The answer is "Yes, but only if there's **some** nonzero lattice point $[u, v]$ with the property that $H_{uv}$ contains $\beta$."

Now let's look at a rather large set of real numbers. Let
$$
L = \bigcup_{(u, v) \in \zz^2\\ (u, v) \ne (0,0)} H_{uv}.
$$

If $\beta$ is some number **not** in $L$, then $S$ cannot be the projection of *any* sublattice!

Now $L$ is a countable union of countable sets, and hence is a countable set. But the reals are uncountable, so $\mathbb R \setminus L$ is nonempty. If we pick $\beta$ to be any element of this set, then our set $S$ will *not* be the projection of any rotated lattice.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question "Does there always exist...", the answer is no, as can be seen with a little linear algebra and group theory.

If $L$ is a line through the origin of $\mathbb R^2$ then $L$ is a vector subspace of $\mathbb R^2$, with operations of vector addition and scalar multiplication obtained by restricting those operations from $\mathbb R^2$. The projection map $\pi : \mathbb R^2 \to L$ is a linear function, and so in particular it is a group homomorphism with respect to addition. Since $\mathbb Z^2$ is an additive subgroup of $\mathbb R^2$, it follows that $\pi(\mathbb Z^2)$ is an additive subgroup of $L$. Furthermore, this subgroup $\pi(\mathbb Z^2)$ is free abelian of rank equal to either $1$ or $2$ (depending on whether the slope of $L$ is rational or irrational). It follows that if $X \subset \pi(\mathbb Z^2)$ then the additive subgroup of $L$ generated by $X$ is free abelian of rank equal to either $1$ or $2$.

So to get counterexamples, what you can do is to write down a discrete subset $X \subset L$ such that the additive subgroup of $L$ generated by $X$ does not have rank $1$ or $2$. Take, for example, a 3 point subset $X \subset L$ which is linearly independent over the field $\mathbb Q$: starting with any nonzero point $p \in L$, the subset
$$X = \{p,\sqrt{2} p, \sqrt{3} p\}
$$
does not lie in the projection of $\mathbb Z^2$ to $L$, because the set $\{1,\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3}\}$ is linearly independent over $\mathbb Q$.

Generally speaking, $L$ has lots of linearly independent sets of any finite size $n \ge 2$, and each of them will provide counterexamples. Also, each of them can produces an infinite, "$n$-fold quasiperiodic set" as you allude to (although that's beyond the scope of what you asked).